# UIBarButtonItem not rotate correctly

Tags: objective-c, ios11, uibarbuttonitem, cgaffinetransform

This code is working before iOS 11, but the rotate is not working proberly on iOS 11.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *reloadBtn;

- (void)buttonRotate
{
    UIView *view = [self.reloadBtn valueForKey:@"view"];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^{
        view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 180 / 180.0);
        view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 360 / 180.0);
    }];

}
```

How can I fix this!

Comment: I was able to fix it by moving `animateWithDuration:` into main thread block ( `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { }` ), could you try that?

Comment: The reloadBtn was rotated but not in center!!

Comment: Does it have a custom image? Maybe it's about the anchor point of the button, it could've been changed in iOS11. I've tried it with "Fast Forward" button (in iOS11 and iOS11.1) and the rotation works. It could also be the image draw mode (should be center).

Comment: `[self.reloadBtn valueForKey:@"view"]` looks pretty hacky - what exactly are you trying to achieve here? Could you use `initWithCustomView:` and rotate that instead?